# Validating array of different object shapes in yup

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formik, yup

I am using formik for form validation and came across some problems in array validation.
here is my form structure

```
{
 flow: [
  { text: "hello"
  },
  { input: "world"
  },
  { buttons: [
       'hi',
       'hello'
     ]
  }
 ]
}
```

I have to create validation schema for this. So the array may contain any of these objects.

I tried this,

```
export const validationSchema = yup.object().shape({
  flow: yup.array().of(
      yup.mixed().oneOf([
        {
          text: yup.string().required('Enter text'),
        },
        {
          buttons: yup.array().of(yup.string().required('Enter button title')),
        },
        {
          input: yup.string(),
        }
      ])
  ),
});
```

But am getting the following as formik error :

```
flow:[

"flow[0] must be one of the following values: [object Object], [object Object]",
"flow[1] must be one of the following values: [object Object], [object Object]"

]
```

How to solve this?

Comment: Hello, did you managed to solve this? I am facing a similar problem and I saw polymorphism must be solved with yup lazy but I do not manage to make it work. Thank you in advance and regards

Answer (score 3):

```
import { array, object, string, lazy } from 'yup';    

const differentObjectsArraySchema = array().of(lazy((item) => {
    const { type } = item;

    // any other condition
    if (type === 'text') {
        return object({
            text: string(),
        });
    }

    if (type === 'buttons') {
        return object({
            buttons: array(),
        });
    }

    if (type === 'input') {
        return object({
            input: string(),
        });
    }
}));
```

source: https://github.com/jquense/yup#yuplazyvalue-any--schema-lazy

Answer (score 0):

Maybe new custom schema type is a solution, but what about array schema with custom test function (with anyof logic)? In example below is just simple validity checking.
https://codesandbox.io/s/yup-anyof-array-w0cww

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't achieve this feature using Yup, I switched to [joi](https://www.npmjs.com/package/joi) and rewrite my two apps(it was very easy because the libraries have a lot of similarity between them) that I used Yup with them, joi support this feature out of the box along with other amazing features.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an adaptation [cb109](https://gist.github.com/cb109/8eda798a4179dc21e46922a5fbb98be6) example that runs with [runkit](https://npm.runkit.com/yup):

```
var yup = require("yup")

yup.addMethod(yup.array, 'oneOfSchemas', function oneOfSchemas(
    schemas,
    message,
) {
    return this.test(
        'one-of-schemas-exact',
        message || 'Not all items in ${path} match one of the allowed schemas',
        (items) =>
            items.every(item => schemas.some(schema => schema.isValidSync(item, { strict: true }))),
    );
});

const validationSchema = yup.object().shape({
  flow: yup.array().oneOfSchemas([
        yup.object({
          text: yup.string().required('Enter text'),
        }),
        yup.object({
          buttons: yup.array().of(yup.string().required('Enter button title')).required(),
        }),
        yup.object({
          input: yup.string().required(),
        })
      ])
});

const passes = validationSchema.validateSync({
 flow: [
  { text: "hello"
  },
  { input: "world"
  },
  { buttons: [
       'hi',
       'hello'
     ]
  }
 ]
})
console.log(passes);

// Fails
validationSchema.validateSync({
 flow: [
  { bad_input: "hello"
  },
  { input: "world"
  },
  { buttons: [
       'hi',
       'hello'
     ]
  }
 ]
})
```

**Importand gotcha**: if you skip `.required()` the objects will always match and the test will always return false. I.e. make sure that the objects have unique patterns and don't overlap.

For a TypeScript implementation it works poorly. I've managed to adapt the original *.d.ts* with something like this:

````
import { AnyObject, ObjectSchema } from 'yup';

// Not exported from yup
type Flags = 's' | 'd' | '';

declare module 'yup' {
  export interface ArraySchema<
    TIn extends any[] | null | undefined,
    TContext,
    TDefault = undefined,
    TFlags extends Flags = ''
  > {
    /**
     * Allows you to define mutliple disparate types which should
     * be considered valid within a single array. You can tell the method
     * what types of schemas to expect by passing the schema types:
     *
     * ```
     * // Array of object schemas
     * yup.array().oneOfSchemas<yup.ObjectSchema>([
     *     yup.object().shape({ ... })
     * ]);
     *
     * // Array of object or string schemas
     * yup.array().oneOfSchemas<yup.ObjectSchema | yup.StringSchema>([
     *     yup.object().shape({ ... }),
     *     yup.string()
     * ]);
     * ```
     *
     * @param schemas A list of yup schema definitions
     * @param message The message to display when a schema is invalid
     */
    oneOfSchemas<TIn1 extends AnyObject, TIn2 extends AnyObject>(
      schemas: [ObjectSchema<TIn1, TContext>, ObjectSchema<TIn2, TContext>],
      message?: string
    ): ArraySchema<(TIn1 | TIn2)[], TContext, TFlags>;
    oneOfSchemas<
      TIn1 extends AnyObject,
      TIn2 extends AnyObject,
      TIn3 extends AnyObject
    >(
      schemas: [
        ObjectSchema<TIn1, TContext>,
        ObjectSchema<TIn2, TContext>,
        ObjectSchema<TIn3, TContext>
      ],
      message?: string
    ): ArraySchema<(TIn1 | TIn2 | TIn3)[], TContext, TFlags>;
    oneOfSchemas<
      TIn1 extends AnyObject,
      TIn2 extends AnyObject,
      TIn3 extends AnyObject,
      TIn4 extends AnyObject
    >(
      schemas: [
        ObjectSchema<TIn1, TContext>,
        ObjectSchema<TIn2, TContext>,
        ObjectSchema<TIn3, TContext>,
        ObjectSchema<TIn4, TContext>
      ],
      message?: string
    ): ArraySchema<(TIn1 | TIn2 | TIn3 | TIn4)[], TContext, TFlags>;
    // Add more variants as needed
  }
}
````

Anyone with a nicer solution is most welcome to contribute!

The actual definition is also not the prettiest:

```
/* eslint-disable no-template-curly-in-string */
import { addMethod, array, MixedSchema } from 'yup';

addMethod(
  // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/ban-ts-comment
  // @ts-ignore
  array,
  'oneOfSchemas',
  function oneOfSchemas(schemas: MixedSchema[], message?: string) {
    return this.test(
      'one-of-schemas',
      message || 'Not all items in ${path} match one of the allowed schemas',
      (items: unknown[]) =>
        items.every((item) =>
          schemas.some((schema) => schema.isValidSync(item, { strict: true }))
        )
    );
  }
);
```

Answer (score -1):

If you look at the function signature for the `oneOf` method:

```
mixed.oneOf(arrayOfValues: Array<any>, message?: string | function): Schema
```

The first parameter is an array of `any`, so any value will be valid within the array in the first parameter.  It's the second `message` argument that can only be a string/function.

That being said, your code does look correct, so I'm not sure why you'd be receiving any errors.  Maybe try adding a message argument and see if that will placate things.  What is the exact error you're receiving, if there is one?

Comment: the validation is not working. am not getting any error message

Comment: Try creating an array of Yup.object.shape({ ...values }).

Comment: Did you test this array of `Yup.object`s? Accordingly to the docs, it doesn't accept yup types, only actual values, so it will check if the value received is equal to the `yup.object` (no validation).